# Cannot link default.aspx to master page please help. content place holder

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have had a lesson on visual studios for an asp.net and am stumped on this master page please help me. I cannot link the default pages to the master page I am not sure

default page code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AdrianASP2012.WebForm2" %>

        <div>
            <h2>Nulla luctus eleifend</h2>
            <p>This is <strong>Greenness </strong>, a free, fully standards-compliant CSS template designed by <a href="http://www.freecsstemplates.org">FCT</a>.   The photos in this template are from <a href="http://fotogrph.com/"> Fotogrph</a>. This free template is released under a <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/">Creative Commons Attributions 3.0</a> license, so you are pretty much free to do whatever you want with it (even use it commercially) provided you keep the links in the footer intact. Aside from that, have fun with it :) </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Maecenas pede nisl, elementum eu, ornare ac, malesuada at, erat. Proin gravida orci porttitor enim accumsan lacinia. Donec condimentum, urna non molestie semper, ligula enim ornare nibh, quis laoreet eros quam eget ante. Aliquam libero. Vivamus nisl nibh, iaculis vitae, viverra sit amet, ullamcorper vitae, turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum dui sem, pulvinar sed, imperdiet nec, iaculis nec, leo. Fusce odio. Etiam arcu dui, faucibus eget, placerat vel, sodales eget, orci. Donec ornare neque ac sem. Mauris aliquet. </p>
            <p class="button-style"><a href="#">More Details</a></p>
        </div>
```

and master page body section is

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">Greenness</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="2" title="">Our Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="3" title="">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="banner-wrapper">
            <div id="banner">
                <img src="App_Themes/Theme1/images/pics01.jpg" width="1000" height="345" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div id="page">
                <div id="content">

                    <!-- CONTENT PLACE HOLDER HERE -->
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


                </div>
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <h2>Maecenas  lectus</h2>
                    <ul class="style1">
                        <li class="first">
                            <p><a href="#">Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique ante ut risus. Quisque dictum. Integer nisl risus, sagittis convallis, rutrum congue.</a></p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><a href="#">Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique ante ut risus. Quisque dictum. Integer nisl risus, sagittis convallis, rutrum congue.</a></p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><a href="#">Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique ante ut risus. Quisque dictum. Integer nisl risus, sagittis convallis, rutrum congue.</a></p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-wrapper">
            <div id="footer-content">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <div id="fbox2">
                    <h2><span>Fusce ultrices</span> fringilla</h2>
                    <p>
                        <img src="App_Themes/Theme1/images/img05.jpg" width="320" height="150" alt="" />
                    </p>
                    <p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique ante ut risus. Quisque dictum. Integer nisl risus, sagittis convallis, rutrum id, elementum congue, nibh. Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum elementum congue.</p>
                    <p class="button-style"><a href="#">More Details</a></p>
                </div>
                <div id="fbox3">
                    <h2><span>Mauris vulputate</span> scelerisque</h2>
                    <ul class="style3">
                        <li class="first">
                            <img src="App_Themes/Theme1/images/img02.jpg" width="78" height="78" alt="">
                            <p>Nullam non wisi a sem eleifend. Donec mattis libero eget urna. </p>
                            <p class="posted">August 11, 2002  |  (10 )  Comments</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="App_Themes/Theme1/images/img03.jpg" width="78" height="78" alt="">
                            <p>Nullam non wisi a sem eleifend. Donec mattis libero eget urna. </p>
                            <p class="posted">August 11, 2002  |  (10 )  Comments</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="App_Themes/Theme1/images/img04.jpg" width="78" height="78" alt="">
                            <p>Nullam non wisi a sem eleifend. Donec mattis libero eget urna. </p>
                            <p class="posted">August 11, 2002  |  (10 )  Comments</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give the MasterPageFile name in your MasterPageFile="~/YourMasterPage.master" 
Second you have to write code inside the content place holder..

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing:

```
MasterPageFile=""
```

to the name of your master page.  Typically:

```
MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your default.aspx `MasterPageFile` value is empty. So change it to your master page file name.

```
MasterPageFile="<place master page path>"

MasterPageFile="~/Custom/UI/Templates/MasterPage.master"
```

HINT : place the cursor between the "" ( MasterPageFile="|" ), and press Ctrl + Space bar for   intellisence and you will get `"Pick Master..."` and click to pick master page.